# arp -a command doesn't consider my smartphone

Tags: arp

I'm a bit of a newbie, so bare with me, please.

So long story short, I've been thinking about being hacked a lot lately, probably due to a (very well made) documentary I watched recently - this might be paranoid, but it is what it is.

I was browsing 9gag today when me opening a new tab redirected me to a reCAPTCHA page to prove I'm not human and it said one of the possible reasons was that my IP was changed. And so my quest for truth began. I ran a batch of the sites I've visited through the McAfee WebAdvisor and it claimed they're all safe. I've been running F-Secure on my computer and it hasn't found any issues so far.

So I did a bit of reading and tried to find how many devices are using my Wi-Fi - I read that the arp -a command gives you the IP's of devices using your Internet and that switching them 1 by 1 will result in the number of IP's decreasing by 1. And this is the problem - the amount of devices was the same regardless of whether my phone's Wi-Fi was turned on or off. Is that good, bad or doesn't even matter? Also, how can I efficiently find if there's an external connection to the network at home/my computer/my phone without using ARP

I'm trying to educate myself a bit more on the topic to avoid such panic thoughts so any tips and any help will be much appreciated. Also, apologies for the long post, but I thought that the whole story would show a more clear picture.

Comment: The ARP table is generally able to retain devices even after losing connection for up to 4 hours. Besides that, I think that scanning your WiFi device list is irrational and doesn't actually give you any indication you're being 'hacked' (unless they had physically mounted an hidden camera in your place, connected to your WiFi or something of that nature). If one of your devices were hacked they would use that device's wifi.

Comment: @nbokmans Thank you very much, I appreciate it! I'm indeed quite new to all of this so the advice is very much welcomed. If it's not too much to ask for, what would you suggest for me to do in order to minimize any chance of potential problems? I read about the "netstat" command and how to manually go through all IP's listed - does that sound like a good idea?